# HQL Hive dfs command Conditional Logic

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hql

Within an HQL script I have an dfs cp command.  Under normal operations the script runs and successfully completes.  A couple scenarios where the script fails is if

1. The source or target directory doesnt exist
2. There is no file in the source directory

In such cases it will return errors such as:

- `cp:`\source_directory/*': No such file or directory`

**Is it possible to have the script continue and ignore this case when the source file or directory doesn't exist?**  I would like to use the script during my initial load process during which time the files wont exist and wont need copied as well as during my daily loads at which time the files would be available and need to be copied.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement any logic you want in bash and run the bash script from the hql file using the `!` directive.

From [hql documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli#LanguageManualCli-HiveInteractiveShellCommands):

```
! <command>  Executes a shell command from the Hive shell.
```

Comment: Giving this an upvote as its working.  Seems all hadoop based tools (hive, pig, etc.) can't function without supporting shell wrappers/scripts which is proving very frustrating.  Will turn this to the answer if no others are provided soon that give a built-in way of doing this.